# How to restrict OSB application to a single server when using clustered environment?

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, soa, osb

I have multiple OSB apps on clustered environment.
And an OSB application that have different FTP, JMS and File Proxy services.  FTP Proxy Service runs and put file in local directory of server 1 and put file name in JMS Queue.
that JMS proxy runs inside it java callout check file but File not found Exception is coming . reason is that FTP place file in server 1 and JMS proxy runs on 2nd server .
Is there any solution to restrict all proxies to run on single server. or any other solution to handle this type of situation.

Comment: There must be a way to execute it in HA (High Availability) mode

Comment: I am confused by the question, maybe you can give more details. In weblogic you can target JMS to specific servers, even if they are clustered.

Comment: thanks for replying please check following link for detail.[https://community.oracle.com/message/12699791#12699791]